# vectorization of flip left-right of a 3D matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, flip

I have a 3D matrix of a movie (say a matrix `M` of size J*K*L). I want to flip left right each frame. Using `fliplr(M)` doesn't work as `M` must be a 2-D matrix. I know I can use a for loop of the following:

```
 for ii=1:size(M,3)
     M(:,:,ii)=fliplr( M(:,:,ii) )
 end
```

Is the a "vectorized" way to do it?

More generally speaking, is the a "vectorized" way to do any of Matlab's matrix manipulations (`flipud`, `repmat`, etc) in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use simple indexing:

```
>> M = rand(3,4,5);
>> M(:, end:-1:1, :);
```

This is a lot faster and less resource intensive than `flipdim`, and I think a lot cleaner too.

However, for some people, this particular usage of the `end` keyword is confusing, so if you're one of those people, `flipdim` will do just fine :)

Comment: Thanks, this makes full sense and I like it even better! the fewer special matlab functions I need to remember the better.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid alternative - personally I prefer `flipdim` because it tells me exactly what it is doing. Seeing the code above makes me have to think... This one may be easier to write (don't have to remember a function name), the other is easier to read. The cool thing about SO is that you get both answers, and you can choose.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for

```
M = flipdim(M, 2);
```

This flips an N dimensional matrix along the dimension you specify as the second parameter. Thus, the `flipud` could be replaced with

```
M = flipdim(M, 1);
```

Not sure where you are going with the `repmat` question, but I often find I can use `bsxfun` instead of `repmat`. Look it up.

Comment: Ah, you got it by 9 seconds.  +1 for you, not that you need it.  ;)